# Tensorflow 2 Residual block, addition

Tags: python, tensorflow2.x

I'm having trouble implementing the Residual block properly. When trying to add the input_tensor and the result of the convolution layers together, I get an error that the shapes mismatch. I don't know how to resolve that. I get

```
ValueError: Operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (25, 32) (25, 31)
```

(25, 31) is the input_tensor size. I think having `padding='same'` set in the conv layers rounds it up (25,32) which is why I can't add them.

Actually, printing the shapes gives:

```
input.shape= (None, 25, 31)
out.shape= (None, 25, 32)
```

batch size being the first dim.

How could I pad the input_tensor, for example with zeros to make it the same shape? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
out = tf.keras.layers.Add()([out, tf.pad(input_tensor, [[0,0],[0,0],[0,1]])])
```